# How Would Society Rebuild After A Meteorite Impact?

Tags: society, post-apocalypse, fauna, civilization, meteor

In my book series, this planet called Aztlan is struck by a massive meteorite. The impact and ensuing fallout were basically identical to the Chicxulub impact that wiped out the dinosaurs. However, the extinctions of local fauna and flora were greatly mitigated by the presence of "insurance" populations on other planets prior to the impact. It has been two years since the impact, and here is where things stand as of now:

-The vast majority of the population perished during and shortly after the impact, with the population being reduced from 67,000,000 to 3,349,150. Virtually all cities, towns, and villages have been completely destroyed and the population is hiding out in caves and cenotes.

-75% of local flora and fauna (and basically everything over 100 lbs) has been extirpated from the planet and only exists on other planets as "insurance" populations. Basilosaurs, the massive freshwater whales whose oil is the best starship engine coolant in the galaxy, were once Aztlan's most valuable export. Now, they are one of those aforementioned extirpated species with "insurance" populations elsewhere (although Aztlan is the only planet with deep enough lakes for harvestably large populations of them).

-Before the impact, the planet was home to an early bronze age civilization based primarily on Inca, Aztec, Maya, Olmec, Mapuche, and Puebloan cultures. All advanced technology would have to be imported from other planets. Pre-disaster, FTL travel was accomplished via a combination of the old magic-based methods and technology imported from more advanced worlds (Aztlan was kind of caught in transition).

-The Galaxy is embroiled in the most massive war of its history, so Aztlan can't expect coordinated aid. There are two factions in the war: The Tatians (An empire headed by a cabal of magical space anarchists who caused the impact in the first place through a whole chain of events I'm not getting into for lack of relevance) and the Ishgas (basically space-age Victorians who the Aztlanians don't really have much love for either due to the Ishgas' colonialist past the Ishgas are trying to turn away from but can't because they need the colonies for the war).

-Since interstellar communications are relatively new technology in this universe, signals are relatively short-range and need a line of relay towers for any long-term communications (kind of similar to the beacons from LOTR except automated). Before the disaster, one of the more advanced civilizations had built a massive tower on Aztlan that was a communications hub for the northern part of the galaxy.

-Any other Chicxulub damage that would be present 2 years out from a meteorite impact is a factor.

My question is **how would society recover from such a cataclysmic event, and how long would this take?**

Comment: VTC as too story based. Please search the site for questions about rebuilding after an apocalypse. There are a lot of them and most are closed as too story-based. (a) 99.9% of our technology was created in the last 150 years. You're starting from a condition where humanity already has a tremendous pool of knowledge (even if only in their heads), so the answer is always "less than 150 years." (b) How? is always subjective as it depends on crises that will only ever exist in your story. You have access to interstellar resources - so it will take as long as you wish it to.

Comment: "Two years"?  Nothing is going to be rebuilt, since the planet will still be suffering the aftereffects of the impact.  After two thousand years things might have settled down enough...

Answer (score 0):

### Alone

With the loss of their usefulness as a supplier of a key starship resource, along with a large scale war, there's no value in providing outside assistance. They'll be rebuilding alone and unsupported. Maybe someone will provide some token aid, a few prefab buildings perhaps, but nothing more, they have their own concerns.

Now if you let them keep the basilosaurs it's a much more interesting concept as the great powers bid to provide aid in exchange for a controlling interest in the supply chain.

Comment: See my edits to the Basilosaur section.

Comment: @TheWeaselSagas, while spice existed on only one planet, control of that planet was contested. Once that was no longer the case, the planet was no longer important. You're looking at a situation no different to that. Deeper oceans are easier to engineer than recovering a planet from an extinction level event.

Answer (score 0):

#### Without magic - they won't.

#### With magic - soil recovery time dominates.

So after the Chicxulub impact, you have this [crazy period:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicxulub_crater#Chicxulub_and_mass_extinction)

- A few years, "possible a decade" waiting for the temperature to get above freezing.
- A decade of blocked sun killing everything from plants up the food chain.
- The end of the dust may be heralded with a sudden, dramatic, greenhouse effect due to the [increases in Carbon Dioxide and Carbon monoxide](https://www.nature.com/news/2009/090513/full/news.2009.477.html). (Vaporised rocks give off huge amount of carbon, everything alive is dying and giving off gases, and no photosynthesis to suck out CO<sub>2</sub>).
- Acid rains will poison all the soil, all the water aquifers, springs, and lakes. You will have to clean that, or wait for it to resolve naturally.

That sequence can delay your rebuilding for dozens, possibly hundreds of years. A modern society with the safety of bunkers and very good stocks could try to speed up the recovery with a massive industrial effort, maybe build a domed community to start rebuilding cities while the air remains toxic.

Bronze age people - they will have to wait it out in caves. As the world freezes. Then becomes toxic to breathe. Then becomes super hot. Then becomes poisoned. They all die very soon of freezing, heatstroke, suffocation, asphyxia, or poison. Or some combination.

But that's a terrible story and you have magic and imported advanced technology, so let's assume you use one / both of them to survive that crazy period with a force field, food maker, water maker, air maker, and waste removal.

Let's call that period 20 years. I've seen estimated ranging from 2 years to 500 years, but for the moment let's assume they spend 20 years in the cave with magic / advanced tech keeping them provided with food, water, and breathable air.

#### Once the outside is safe again - only agriculture really matters.

Once that period is over, the air is breathable and a decent temperature, and the poison has gone from the water table; they can get to work. 3 million people, organised, disciplined, well supplied, prepared, and able to relax in comfort in their underground bunker after a long day, could get quick settlements built in a month (each family constructs 1 building each for shelter and their trade), and their entire non-food lives up and running within a year. Add a few months into that if they need to scout, add another few if they need to make tools, but it really doesn't matter cause rebuilding is only a tiny part of recovering.

Recovering food production is going to be tricky.

All the topsoil is ruined by acid rains. Most of the plants died, and those that survived are small in number and recovering themselves. You're going to have restart your agriculture from scratch.

[It takes 100 years to recover 25mm (1in) of topsoil](https://www.farmprogress.com/land-management/how-long-does-it-take-build-organic-matter), and growing veggies needs ["at least" 150mm (6in)](https://www.bhg.com/gardening/yard/soil/topsoil/) of topsoil. That suggests you're looking at 600 years to get agriculture up to the level it was before the impact.

That 600 years dominates the recovery time. 20 years waiting for the planet to be survivable, and a year building a small city, barely rates a mention.